# Selenium Webdriver with Python: Firefox Profile Handling

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-profile

I have created a new firefox profile, that I want to use for the automated tests. When calling firefox manually with this profile then I see the menu bar and the bookmarks toolbar.

But when using this profile within my code I still get no menubar and no bookmarks toolbar

```
myprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:/Users/xxxxx/Documents/1tm2mblc.WebDriver_Profile')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\eclipse\\geckodriver.exe", firefox_profile=myprofile)
```

So the behaviour is exactly the same as if I don't specify any profile at all.
If I put a typo in the profile path then I get an error message, so the profile seems not to be ignored...

Geckodriver log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/awg3kv2x1lqetpo/geckodriver.log?dl=0

Logfile with DEBUG Trace Level contains the following lines:

```
02/02/2018 12:50:44 PM POST http://127.0.0.1:55237/session {"capabilities": {"firstMatch": [{}], "alwaysMatch": {"browserName": "firefox", "acceptInsecureCerts": true, "moz:firefoxOptions": {"profile": "UEsDBBQAAAAIADBGQUygpt2X......" 
02/02/2018 12:51:15 PM Finished Request {'value': {'sessionId': 'ebdcc867-62c8-4c8c-900b-ba272fd15345', 'capabilities': {'acceptInsecureCerts': True, 'browserName': 'firefox', 'browserVersion': '58.0.1', 'moz:accessibilityChecks': False, 'moz:headless': False, 'moz:processID': 5316, 'moz:profile': 'C:\\Users\\herololi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.8xCt6R02aSkK', 'moz:webdriverClick': True, 'pageLoadStrategy': 'normal', 'platformName': 'windows_nt', 'platformVersion': '6.1', 'rotatable': False, 'timeouts': {'implicit': 0, 'pageLoad': 300000, 'script': 30000}}}} 
02/02/2018 12:51:15 PM POST http://127.0.0.1:55237/session/ebdcc867-62c8-4c8c-900b-ba272fd15345/url {"url": "http://only-testing-blog.blogspot.in/2014/05/login.html"} 
02/02/2018 12:51:25 PM Finished Request {'value': {}} 
02/02/2018 12:51:25 PM POST http://127.0.0.1:55237/session/ebdcc867-62c8-4c8c-900b-ba272fd15345/timeouts {"implicit": 20000} 
02/02/2018 12:51:25 PM Finished Request {'value': {}} 
02/02/2018 12:51:30 PM DELETE http://127.0.0.1:55237/session/ebdcc867-62c8-4c8c-900b-ba272fd15345/window {} 
02/02/2018 12:51:32 PM Finished Request {'value': []}
```

Please note that I have truncated the first line, as the profile entry is incredibly long and makes the file (with only 8 lines) 224 MB big...

Any advice? Thanks

Python 3.6.4

Selenium Webdriver 3.8.1

Comment: Can you update the question with the geckodriver trace logs which can help us to debug whats going wrong?

Comment: Link to geckodriver log added. Thanks!

Comment: Can you update the question with the trace logs please?

Comment: Done, please let me know if you were asking for other log file. Thanks!

Comment: Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58620609/6521116), it may helps.